# EclipseLink Static Weaving with Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, eclipselink

I'm using IntelliJ and I want my unit tests to be run or debug with static weaving for lazy loading et al. I know that unlike Eclipse that IntelliJ does not have a static weaving step but I imagine someone must have setup IntelliJ to statically weave before running or debugging tests.

So far I have tried dynamic weaving with the JVM argument of -javaagent:./path/eclipselink-2.5.0.jar but that doesn't seem to work. I still get these warnings:

```
[EL Warning]: metadata: 2013-08-28 11:00:51.091--ServerSession(1610028911)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [owner] for the entity class [class com.my.Contact] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
```

Do my IntelliJ brother and sisters just punt on this and skip weaving in the IDE? Do we just not use EclipseLink or have we figured out how to handle the static weaving and still use IntelliJ?

Thanks!

Comment: how about the static weaving?

Comment: Trouble is that IDEA does this even when we have static weaving. After complete maven build, classes are weaved, it can be checked with javap, but IDEA somehow picks (or recreates?) vanilla classes and this error appears. To make a matter worse, sometimes it works OK, sometimes it doesn't. Don't know what makes idea to touch those classes...

Answer (score 2):

You can create additional build steps before launching a run configuration.

- Run > Edit Configurations…
- Select the desired run configuration
- Add your static weaver compiler as additional build step under `Before Launch:

  - For example add a Maven goal like `eclipselink:weave`
  - Or execute a java process like `java org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeave…`
  - Position should be between `Build` and `Build artifact``
- See Screenshot: [image: Define additional build steps]

Another solution is to define the Maven goal as a hook for `After Build` in the Maven tool window. Just right-click on the appropriate Maven goal and select `Execute After Build`. This will execute the EclipseLink Weaver via Maven everytime after `Build` is executed. You will see the hook in parenthesis behind the Maven goal:

[image: Create a Maven goal build hook in IDEA]

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ Idea can run additional targets to build the application.

If you have an maven project with staticweave plugin configured, it is possible to add a maven "process-classes" goal to perform staticweave actions automatically on idea build run.